# iterparse in ElementTree eating memory

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, iterparse

I have written the following code to read XML/OSM data on Toronto from Open Street Map and get a list of all the postcodes.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

file = 'sample_map.osm'

for event, elem in iterparse(file): 
    nodes = elem.findall('node')
    for oneN in nodes:
        try:        
            tags = oneN.findall('tag')
            for oneTag in tags:
                if oneTag.attrib['k'] == 'addr:postcode':
                    print (oneTag.attrib['v'])
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        oneN.clear()
```

While the code outputs the result from a 9 MB file having sample data in 1 second, when I rum it on the file having data from whole of the Toronto (1.15 GB), it eats whole of the PC memory and takes forever.

I assume using iterparse and oneN.clear() should free-up my memory while running the main loop. Can someone please guide me what am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: If you add `elem.clear()` at the end of the `for` loop, does it make a difference?

Comment: @mzjn Thanks! It worked.